# Will different database helper object always access to same database and share value?if so why do we need singleton? android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

im new to android, i have one question about database access by using SQLite database, here is the quesion.

```
NoteDBHelper helper1 = new NoteDBHelper(this);
NoteDBHelper helper2 = new NoteDBHelper(this);
```

once i use helper1 variable insert some value to database, will i get those value from helper2?  what i mean is will these two objects share one database when using it in two different activities?

```
public class NoteDBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public NoteDBHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

---

hi guys, ive tried ,it shows these two objects will share values each other, but i want to know the concept, because i think different object alway have their own values, so that they should have their own database with same name, but the fact is it shares same database?

Comment: i've tried on android studio, and these two objects will share value, but i really dont understand the concept, cuz i think differernt object will have their own database and values.

Comment: It might look like that but not really. The helper is accessing a specific SQLite file located at your `data/data/{your package}/databases/yourdb` which is just the same across all instance. In other words the 2 instance are just performing CRUD on the same file

Comment: thaks a lot, do u know the document  explain those concept  heple me further understanding.

Comment: The documentation for SQLite is found in https://sqlite.org/ .